# How do I display a formatted date in Vue while populating input boxes

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible when populating input boxes with Vue from an object to display a formatted date in the input box?

This is how the input box is populated with `:vue`

```
<input type="text" id="Example" :value="v.date" spellcheck="false">
```

v.date is the date as stored in the object `Timestamp(seconds=1576436040, nanoseconds=0)`

In the end I would like the input box to display the date as `15 December 2019 19:54`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`toDate()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#to-date) method of the Timestamp.

You can either call this method when you populate the `v.date` value (after fetching the data from Firestore I guess) or by doing

```
<input type="text" id="Example" :value="v.date.toDate()" spellcheck="false">
```

Comment: Is there a way to ignore the part after the time `GMT+0100 (Midden-Europese standaardtijd)`

Comment: You can use the `moment.js` library to format the date. For example, you calculate the formatted date in a computed value.

Comment: You can do something like `this.v.date = moment(doc.data().created.toDate()).format("DD MMMM YYYY, hh:mm");`